# What land is the Evil Queen ruler of?

Tags: shrek

In Shrek the Third, we see the Evil Queen as a minor antagonist. But what was she Queen of? Duloc? Far Far Away? If she was Queen of Duloc, that would explain how Farquaad got the Mirror. But if Far Far Away, is she Queen Lillian’s step sister?

Comment: I didn't think Duloc was a kingdom since Farquaad is only a Lord? I suppose it could be whatever kingdom encompasses Duloc? I don't think it can be Far Far Away because that's where Snow White lives with her dwarves and the Evil Queen is traditionally located far from Snow White.